# Get .parent() in JQuery after various .append()

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm having a problem in JQuery using the functions .parent(), .append() and .closest()

Case:

I'm appending some `<li>` elements to an `<ul>` element like this:

```
this.$element.find('option').each(function(i, element) {
    var $option = $(this);
    var $liOption = $('<li data-value="'+$option.attr('value') + '">' + $option.html() + '</li>');

    ...

    _this.$optionContainer.append($liOption);
}
```

So, when the first element is appended, debugging I can see the `<ul>` with $liOption.parent(), but when the second element is appended, when I try to use .parent() in the first, it returns empty

This is causing me problems for using the .closest() function, as it results empty too not having parents.

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you possible create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/wt536yxf/